# Can i remove / ignore files with a build command generated by webpack?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, webpack

I am using the [`wp-scripts` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css) to generate some files. Internally `wp-scripts` uses `webpack`. The project is created using React and uses modular css.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "wp-scripts build src/index.js src/save.js",
    ...
}
```

My package.json build command creates 3 files for every entry point.

**current output**

- index.asset.php
- index.js
- index.css
- save.asset.php
- save.js
- save.css

Only the css file of the `save.js` file is necessary. I don't want the other 2 files in the build.

**desired output**

- index.asset.php
- index.js
- index.css
- save.css

**The question**

So I want to remove 2 specific files.

Can someone explain how to:

- not generate these 2 files in the build command ( preferred approach )
- remove these 2 files after building them using the build command

*NOTE: Currently I can either remove the files manually or keep them. It won't affect the project much. But I'd rather have it automated as I will probably forget to remove the files and make the build bigger than necessary.*